# How to generate fragments from firebase?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I want to import from Firebase some categories as fragments , i want to know how i can do that , to generate fragments for each category . I think this question is objective enough and doesn't need code ..

Comment: this question is way too broad... stack overflow is for questions with code and some bugs/problems (check out rules), not for complex solutions and architecture

Comment: oh okay , but i really didn't find a solution for that though..

Comment: i am expecting a link to some documentation or something like that